# How to smoothly hide action mode tool bar then show action bar

Tags: java, android, android-actionbar, actionmode

I have a recycler view and when user long clicks an item, I begin an action mode with `beginActionMode` and later finish the action mode when selection is done.

#### PROBLEM

Is when the action mode is finished and it hides its tool bar, I show mine in `onDestroyActionMode`
but the view jerks down then up.

How can I smoothly hide the action mode tool bar then show the action bar without the view jerk.

#### Note

In `beginActionMode` the view does not jerk, it only does so when closing action mode.

here is `beginActionMode`

```java
private boolean beginActionMode () {
  if (fActionMode == null) {
    fSwipeRefereshLayout.setEnabled (false);
    fActionMode = startSupportActionMode (this);
    // I hide the action bar here
    getSupportActionBar ().hide ();
    fSelectingItems = true;
    fSelectedItems.clear ();
    return true;
  }
  fActionMode.invalidate ();
  return false;
}
```

and `onDestroyActionMode`

```java
@Override
public void onDestroyActionMode (ActionMode am) {
  fActionMode = null;
  fSelectingItems = false;

  selectAll ();
  fTabLayout.setClickable (true);
  // I show action bar here
  getSupportActionBar ().show ();
  fSwipeRefereshLayout.setEnabled (true);
}
```

Comment: Everything else works fine.